# Count Span(s) in cells with a specific class within a table (ES5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to count all cells that have a certain class and contains span with a specific class

Here is my td structure:

```
<td class="Yellow">
 Hello Kitty 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" title="Invalid!"></span>
</td>
```

I want to be able to loop through the entire table and get all `.Yellow > span.glyphicon-exclamation-sign`

and finally, do a .count()

I have tried `table.cells('.Yellow').count()` but this only considers `td` with `.Yellow`

Comment: `cells()`? `count()`? Where are these defined?

Comment: @Mitya i'm using datatables js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count it by following...

```
let count=document.querySelectorAll('.Yellow > span.glyphicon-exclamation-sign').length
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out :

```js
var count = 0; //init count is 0

$( "table .Yellow" ).each(function() { // loop through Yellow
    var _block = $(this);
  $( _block).children().each(function() { // loop through childrens 
    if($(this).hasClass("glyphicon")) { //if child has 'glyphicon' class
        count ++; // increase the count by 1
    }
    });
});

$(".indicator").html(count); // show the count
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Table added with two rows. Each row has two TDs with one TD has class "Yellow".</br>
Counting .Yellow > .glyphicon items count using jquery.</br>
Expected output should be "2".

<table>
<tr>
<td class="Yellow">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" title="Invalid!"></span>
</td>
 <td>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" title="Invalid!"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="Yellow">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" title="Invalid!"></span>
</td>
 <td>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" title="Invalid!"></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


<div class="indicator"></div>
```